# I am an advertiser of a Facebook page, how can I add it as a host of an event of another event of which the page i am an editor?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

For a Facebook event I need to add another page as a co-host. I am an editor of the page that is running the event and I am an advertiser of another page, that I am trying to add to the event, the edit section of the event page won't allow me to add pages, just people.